# How to handle on click on GridView react native android?

Tags: android, react-native

I have implemented `grid view` in react native.It gets data from json and displays.
Now I want to click the `grid item` and display the content on the basis of data on current position of `grid`.

[Implemented grid view using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-grid-view)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the Touchable components with `onPress` handler.

For example [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html#content).

You can pass the navigator as props as shown in `renderScene` section of the example below.

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import GridView from 'react-native-grid-view';
import Movie from './Movie.js';
import MovieDetail from './MovieDetail.js';

class ReactNativeGridViewTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: ['hello', 'blabla', 'BatMan', 'SuperMan']
    };
  }
  onHandleItemPress(item){
    this.refs.navigator.push({
      id: 'detail',
      data:item
    });
  }
  renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onHandleItemPress.bind(this, item)}>
        <View>
          <Movie item={item}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
  renderScene(route,navigator){
    switch(route.id){
      case 'master': return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <GridView
            items={this.state.movies}
            itemsPerRow={3}
            renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
          />
        </View>
       )
      case 'detail': return (<MovieDetail navigator={navigator} data={route.data}/>)
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator ref="navigator" 
      initialRoute={{id: 'master'}}renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}/>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeGridViewTest', () => ReactNativeGridViewTest);
```

**Movie.js**

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Movie extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={{width:40, height:40, margin: 20, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
         <Text>{this.props.item}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

**MovieDetail.js**

```
import React, {
  AppRegistry,
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

export default class MovieDetail extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={()=> this.props.navigator.pop()}>
          <Text>Go Back </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <View style={{width:40, height:40, margin: 20, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
           <Text>{this.props.data}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

You can also check out the [working example on Github](https://github.com/agenthunt/react-native-scratchpad/tree/master/ReactNativeGridViewTest).

Comment: This is not rendering the view.Grid view is not appearing.And also how to pass the navigator reference to Movi e class.

Comment: Thanks for the update,but on running it renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)} binds it to Movie screen only.On click of item on Movie screen it is not taking to Movie Detail Screen.,again rendering Movie Screen in my case

Comment: Can you share your complete code somewhere ? Have you tried the working example at https://github.com/agenthunt/react-native-scratchpad/tree/master/ReactNativeGridViewTest ?